# ios swift - unreleased memory when appending uiimage to array

Tags: ios, memory

I'm appending uiimages from core data to an array in order to create a gif of them.

I'm creating the gif and then emptying the array; however, I still have an indefinite 50 mb memory allocation from the moment I create the gif.

I tried looking at instruments and this is what I'm getting in the call tree:

[Call tree image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iR1k.png)

This is the code:

```
     do{
            let objects = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(request)

            let results = objects

            if results.count > 0 {
                for var i = 0; i < results.count; i += 1{
                    let match = results[i] as! cFW
                    date.append(match.date)
                    let image = match.image
                    fetchedImage.append(UIImage(data: image)!)
                }
            } else {

            }
        }
        catch{}
```

Even after deleting the gif and the array already being deleted, the app stays at 50mb of memory usage.

Thank you

**edit: The issue that I'm having has to do with how I'm displaying the gif (in a webview). I will update the question with my solution asap**

Comment: so are you ever removing all the contents in fetchedImage ? When do you remove it

Comment: Right after creating the gif. After further investigation, found a post on another site of someone having a similar issue: "Did some more research in to this using Instruments and noticed that VM: ImageIO_GIF_Data gets called once for every frame in the GIF. I also noticed that the amount of memory allocated each time it gets called is equal to the size of the GIF, which would imply that iOS is reallocating the whole image for every frame in it when you assign an animated instance of UIImage to a UIImageView."

Comment: If you are viewing the image in a web view is probably just the web view cache

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening due to presenting the gif in a webview.

Clearing the cache of web view did not resolve the allocation of memory.

I ended up using a library to FLAnimatedImage to present my GIF.

No more unreleased memory.

Thank you guys